# What does 'Inequality constraints incompatible' when fitting an AR-EGARCH-model mean in Python?

Tags: python, forecasting, convergence, inequality, arch

I am trying to fit an AR-EGARCH(1,1) model to electricity prices and forecast the day ahead. I am modelling every hour sepereatly, so I forecast the price for hour 0-1 only with the time series which consists of the prices in this hour from the past 1000 days. To get all 24 hours I am doing this 23 times for each hour. The forecast seems good most of the times, but sometimes it leads to large prices like -8000 (normally it's around 40), and every time it does this, the message :

**"arch/univariate/base.py:750: ConvergenceWarning: The optimizer returned code 4. The message is:
Inequality constraints incompatible
See scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp for code meaning"**

shows up (not on a regular basis and for different hours). How can I fix this?

```
def forecast_ar_garch_egarch_hourly(first_forecast_start,seasonality,distribution,length):
   
    df_ar_egarch=pd.DataFrame()
    
    for i in range(0,24): # for each hour
        #get electricity prices for hour i in one dataframe
        electricity_prices_hour_i= pd.DataFrame(electricity_prices[electricity_prices['hour']==i]['Price'],index=electricity_prices[electricity_prices['hour']==i].index)
        #forecast start
        forecast_day=first_forecast_day+d.timedelta(hours=i)
        #how much past data should be included
        start_model=forecast_day-d.timedelta(days=length) 
        end_model=forecast_day-d.timedelta(days=1)
        
        df_hour_i=electricity_prices_hour_i[start_model:end_model]
        
        #use pmdarima.auto_arima to get the optimal parameter combination (but only the AR(P)-part)
        diff=ndiffs(df_hour_i,test='adf')
        ar_fit=pm.auto_arima(df_hour_i,max_p=6,start_q=0,max_q=0,d=diff,m=seasonality,start_Q=0,max_Q=0,max_P=16,test='adf',stepwise=True,trace=True)
        p, diff, q= ar_fit.order
        P, Diff, Q, m= ar_fit.seasonal_order
        
        #get prediction from ar_egarch_pred function
        prediction_egarch=ar_egarch_pred(df_stundei,M,seasonality,p,P)
        
        df_ar_egarch=df_ar_egarch.append({'Electricity price EGARCH':prediction_egarch},ignore_index=True)
        i+1
    
    df_ar_egarch.index=pd.date_range(start=first_forecast_start,end=first_forecast_start+d.timedelta(hours=23),freq='60min')
    return(df_ar_garch,df_ar_egarch)

def ar_egarch_pred(data,seasonality,distribution,p,P):
    #distribution : 't','normal' or 'skew'
    #seasonality= frequency of seasonality (=7) since I assume weekly seasonality
    
    #get the AR(p) lags
    lags_ar=[]
    for i in range(1,p+1):
        lags_ar=lags_ar+[i]
    for j in range(0,P):
        lags_ar=lags_ar+[(np.linspace(M,P*M,num=P)[j])]
        
    lags_ar=[int(x) for x in lags_ar]
    
    #fit and forecast with egarch model one step ahead and return this value
    ar_egarch=arch_model(modelldaten,mean='AR',lags=lags_ar,vol='EGARCH',p=1,o=1,q=1,dist=distribution)
    ar_egarch_fit=ar_egarch.fit(first_obs=modelldaten.iloc[0,0],last_obs=modelldaten.iloc[-1,0],options={'maxiter':4000},disp='off')
    forecast=ar_egarch_fit.forecast().mean.iloc[-1,0]
    return(forecast)
```

Comment: Could you solve the issue? I'm having the same problem with a simple GARCH(1, 1) and I don't know how to fix that :(